# How do I fix 'FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.' error inside cli-platform-android\native_modules.gradle?

Tags: react-native

I'm newbie at react native, in my first many times trying to run `npx react-native run-android` i found the error below:

> error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
> Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
> :ReactNative:Unexpected empty result of running '[node, C:\Users\Vitor Hugo\Documents\Programação\Aprendendo-React-Native\CursoFabrica\node_modules@react-native-community\cli\build\bin.js, config]' command.
> :ReactNative:Running '[node, C:\Users\Vitor Hugo\Documents\Programação\Aprendendo-React-Native\CursoFabrica\node_modules@react-native-community\cli\build\bin.js, config]' command failed.
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - Where:
>   Script 'C:\Users\Vitor Hugo\Documents\Programa��o\Aprendendo-React-Native\CursoFabrica\node_modules@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\native_modules.gradle' line: 413
> - What went wrong:
>   A problem occurred evaluating script.
>   node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1078  throw err;  ^Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\Vitor Hugo\Documents\Programação\Aprendendo-React-Native\CursoFabrica\node_modules@react-native-community\cli\build\bin.js'    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1075:15)    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:920:27)    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',  requireStack: []}Node.js v18.15.0

So i tried to clean cache deleting `node_modules` and `package.lock`, but it doesn't work yet. I verified the env variables and they are right:

`JAVA_HOME: C:\Program Files\Microsoft\jdk-11.0.18.10-hotspot`
`ANDROID_HOME: C:\Android\Sdk`

Inside `Path`:

`%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools`
`%ANDROID_HOME%\tools\bin`
`%ANDROID_HOME%\tools`
`%ANDROID_HOME%\emulator`

I had try to install directly the cli through `npm i @react-native-community/cli-platform-android` because I didn't found folder inside node_modules after clean cache, but nothing yet.

I'm grateful for your attetion, if you can please help me.

**Edit1:** after I posted this I noticed that my JAVA_HOME was wrong, it indicating jdk-19 so I fix this and doesn't work yet, the line o error changed but the same error occurs, follow the new log below:

> error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android
> development environment set up:
> https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Error: Command failed:
> gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
> :ReactNative:Unexpected empty result of running '[node, C:\Users\Vitor
> Hugo\Documents\Programação\Aprendendo-React-Native\CursoFabrica\node_modules@react-native-community\cli\build\bin.js,
> config]' command. :ReactNative:Running '[node, C:\Users\Vitor
> Hugo\Documents\Programação\Aprendendo-React-Native\CursoFabrica\node_modules@react-native-community\cli\build\bin.js,
> config]' command failed.
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - Where: Script 'C:\Users\Vitor Hugo\Documents\Programa��o\Aprendendo-React-Native\CursoFabrica\node_modules@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\native_modules.gradle'
>   line: 389
> - What went wrong: A problem occurred evaluating script.
>   node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1078  throw err;  ^Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\Vitor
>   Hugo\Documents\ProgramaÃ§Ã£o\Aprendendo-React-Native\CursoFabrica\node_modules@react-native-community\cli\build\bin.js'
>   at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1075:15)
>   at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:920:27)    at
>   Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain]
>   (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)    at
>   node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
>   requireStack: []}Node.js v18.15.0

Answer (score 0):

It is happening because of your path. Move your project to english-based path